# Multiple resistors to reach needed value?

Tags: voltage, led, resistors, dc

Im converting an old floodlight to a cree led to run off my solar setup for a yard light

I need a 27ohm resistor for a 3.5v 350ma single led to run off 12.5v, but don't have any that value, what multiple resistors to reach that goal can I use instead?

Comment: You do realize that by using a resistor you'll be wasting 2.5x as much power as heat than what your LED will be using don't you ... ?

Comment: Current controlled buck converter would be much, much better. If you go with resistors, be sure you choose a combination that can handle the power (you're burning 3.3W in the resistors - which will make even a couple typical resistors that most folks have handy (1/4 or 1/8 watt) go up in smoke PDQ. 4x110 ohm 1-watt in parallel would be one approach...

Answer (score 1):

You could connect the following sets of resistors in series:

22 ohm + 5 ohm

15 ohm + 12 ohm

20 ohm + 7 ohm

10 ohm + 17 ohm

Alternatively you could hook the following pairs of resistors in parallel:

39 ohm || 87 ohm

56 ohm || 52 ohm

64 ohm || 46 ohm

54 ohm || 54 ohm

100 ohm || 37 ohm

I think you should get the idea.

Comment: For a single resistor it needs to be ~3.3W capable resistor. Higher rating like 5W or 10W highly recommended. In the series resistor pairs the two resistors will split the 3.3W of power in proportion to their individual resistances. Similar behavior for the paralleled resistors the power will share across the pair.

Comment: Thanks guys great answers, lots to think about, It goes to happen I do have most of those values listed above, besides the one rated for watts the ledcalc called for ,and I also have a small adj regulator module that could do the trick too, I think in the bulk lot I bought of them cost .60c each anyway

Answer (score 0):

I think you can buy 27 ohm (standard value) 10 watt (you will want some safety margin) resistors bit it is EXTREMELY wasteful, burning off 3/4 power on this resistor (aka worse than an light bulb). Get a switcher instead maybe. You can get a `MC34063`-based or `LM2596-ADJ`-based solution fairly cheap.